# How to get a value of radio button in the option group Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've an Access 2010 form that contains 2 radio buttons. One for **Yes** and one for **No** in **Option Group**. How do I get the selected value?

i.e. - whether user selected Yes or No, using VBA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option Groups return an integer value starting at 1 and going up from there.  If your option group is called Fld_Opt_Method then try `Me.Fld_Opt_Method`:

`If Me.Fld_Opt_Method = 1 Then msgbox "first option"`
`If Me.Fld_Opt_Method = 2 Then msgbox "second option"`

Comment: To be more explicit you can also use `Me.Fld_Opt_Method.Value`.